# How to add multiple audio to video file at a specific time using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I can add one audio to video by using

```
ffmpeg -i input_video -i input_audio -filter_complex "
aevalsrc=0:d=30[s1];
[s1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[aout]" -c:v copy -map 0:v -map [aout] output_video
```

I have no idea how I can add two, three,... audio to video.
I have searched a lot of post, but I can not find the correct answer.
Thank for your help.

Comment: Do you wish to add generated silence or audio content? At what all times?

Comment: @Gyan I wish I can add audio content like mp3 at specific time. Thanks

Comment: See my answer at https://superuser.com/q/1172109/114058

Comment: @Gyan this answer can be used if my video that is not mute.  I use this String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", originalFileName, "-codec", "copy", "-an", handleFileName};    to make my video mute first.   I use your answer that will get error                                                                   
 ' ' in filtergraph description [1]adelay=1288|1288[b];[2]adelay=1676|1676[c];[0][b][c]amix=4 matches no streams.